# Pseudo-inverse error

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, pseudoinverse

I am trying to find out how to get the error associated with with this equation `G = MD` where I compute the pseudo-inverse of D and left multiply by G to get M.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse of $D$ is a matrix $D^+$ such that $D D^+ D = D$.  If the "error" is $E = M - G D^+ $, this says $E D = 0$, i.e. $E$ annihilates the column space of $D$.  On the other hand, $E v = M v$ for $v \in \text{Ker} D^*$, i.e. vectors orthogonal to the column space of $M$.

Comment: Wouldn't `E = M − GD+` always give you an E of all zeros because `M = GD+`?

Comment: Sorry, I somehow got things turned around.  You want to take $M = G D^+$ as your "approximate solution" to the equation $G = M D$.  The error is then $E = G - M D = G - G D^+ D$.  Now $D^+ D$ is the orthogonal projection on $\text{Ran}D^* = (\text{Ker} D)^\perp$.  So $E v = 0$ for vectors $v$ orthogonal to $\text{Ker}(D)$, while $E v = G v$ for vectors $v \in \text{Ker} D$.